# Passing $this to a function outside class

Tags: php, scope, this

I am calling a function inside a class, function is outside the class. I want to pass `$this` of the class to that function,

currently I am doing this:

```
class foo {   
   func_outside_class($this);
}

function func_outside_class($context){
    return  $context;
}
```

Is there a way so that I don't need to pass context as function parameter.
Or my above code is OK?

I cannot create an object inside function, cause this class need some parameters.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with passing `$this` to an outside function. But I don't understand why you're immediately overwriting the `$context` variable -- why does the function take an argument if it's not using it? Did you mean `$this = $context`?

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake

Comment: In that case, I don't think you can do it. You're not allowed to assign `$this`, it's a special variable that always contains the current object in a class method.

Comment: Ok, I will not use $this

Comment: In the outside function, you can simply do `$context->method(...)` to use it.

Comment: OK, I will remember you advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar wrote:

> There's nothing wrong with passing `$this` to an outside function. But I don't understand why you're immediately overwriting the `$context` variable -- why does the function take an argument if it's not using it? Perhaps you mean `$this = $context`.
>
> If that's that case, I don't think you can do it. You're not allowed to assign `$this`, it's a special variable that always contains the current object in a class method.
>
> In the outside function, you can simply do `$context->method(...)` to use it instead.

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)